# Equivalence Transformations for proving logical statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

I am having trouble figuring out how to solve the following:

\begin{align}
&(\neg p \rightarrow \neg q) \rightarrow ([\neg p \rightarrow q] \rightarrow p)\\
=& (p \lor \neg q) \rightarrow ([\neg p \rightarrow q] \rightarrow p)\\
=&\neg(p \lor \neg q) \lor ([\neg p \rightarrow q] \rightarrow p)\\
=&(\neg p \land q) \lor ([p \lor \neg q] \rightarrow p)\\
=&(\neg p \land q) \lor (\neg[p \lor \neg q] \lor p)\\
=&(\neg p \land q) \lor ([\neg p \land q] \lor p)\\
=&(\neg p \land q) \lor ([\neg p \lor p] \land [q \lor p])\\
=&(\neg p \land q) \lor (T \land [q \lor p])\\
=&(\neg p \land q) \lor (q \lor p)
\end{align}

The thing is that now I do not how to proceed from there.

I could be going about this the completely wrong way but any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Edit 1:
\begin{align}
&(\neg p \rightarrow \neg q) \rightarrow ([\neg p \rightarrow q] \rightarrow p)\\
=& (p \lor \neg q) \rightarrow ([\neg p \rightarrow q] \rightarrow p)\\
=&\neg(p \lor \neg q) \lor ([\neg p \rightarrow q] \rightarrow p)\\
=&(\neg p \land q) \lor ([p \lor q] \rightarrow p)\\
=&(\neg p \land q) \lor (\neg[p \lor q] \lor p)\\
=&(\neg p \land q) \lor ([\neg p \land \neg q] \lor p)\\
=&(\neg p \land q) \lor ([\neg p \lor p] \land [\neg q \lor p])\\
=&(\neg p \land q) \lor (T \land [q \lor p])\\
=&(\neg p \land q) \lor (\neg q \lor p)
\end{align}

I fixed the typo, but I still don't know how to proceed from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the mistake

> \begin{align}
> &(\neg p \rightarrow \neg q) \rightarrow ([\neg p \rightarrow q] \rightarrow p)\\
> =& (p \lor \neg q) \rightarrow ([\neg p \rightarrow q] \rightarrow p)\\
> =&\neg(p \lor \neg q) \lor ([\color{red}{\neg p \rightarrow q}] \rightarrow p)\\
> =&(\neg p \land q) \lor ([\color{red}{p \lor \neg q}] \rightarrow p)\\
> =&(\neg p \land q) \lor (\neg[p \lor \neg q] \lor p)\\
> =&(\neg p \land q) \lor ([\neg p \land q] \lor p)\\
> =&(\neg p \land q) \lor ([\neg p \lor p] \land [q \lor p])\\
> =&(\neg p \land q) \lor (T \land [q \lor p])\\
> =&(\neg p \land q) \lor (q \lor p)
> \end{align}

Comment: Pointing out the mistake is not equivalent to pointing out the mistake and correcting it.

Comment: @amWhy I believe OP knows the right the answer, it's just a typo

Comment: The OP asked for help in answering the question.  The worst way to teach is pointing out mistakes, only.

Comment: I don't agree, I can tell that OP is doing everything fine, simply got lost because of a typo, if we just give the answer, they lost the chance to practice.

Comment: How do you *know* it's a typo???

Comment: @amWhy $P\to Q=\lnot P\lor Q$ applied twice correctly before the mistake

Comment: But you failed to catch the subsequent mistake, so I think you're too quick to think there was only one mistake you consider a typo.

Comment: @amWhy What do you mean by the "subsequent mistake", certainly everything after that typo are not equivalent to before, but isn't this the only mistake?

Comment: It was indeed a typo, I have fixed it and corrected the rest of the answer in the edit. But I still do not know how to proceed

Comment: @TheCeaserSalad Try apply de morgan's law to $(\lnot p\land q)$ that takes $\lnot$ out, you are almost done.

Comment: @Manx I'm not sure I understand, don't I need a negation in order to do De-Morgan's? But in the statement: $(\neg p \land q) \lor (\neg q \lor p)$ there is not a negation in order to do De-Morgan's.

Comment: @TheCeaserSalad It's de morgan's law from another direction: $(\lnot p\land q)\lor(\lnot q\lor p)=\lnot(p\lor\lnot q)\lor(\lnot q\lor p)$

Comment: @Manx I still fail to see how that can help, since at that point it can only be re-written as:
$\neg(p \lor \neg q) \lor \neg q \lor p$ but $\neg(p \lor \neg q)$ is still a term by itself and since it is all $\lor$, the only logical equivalence I can think of is the Associative Law.

Comment: @TheCeaserSalad then by commutative law $¬(p∨¬q)∨(¬q∨p) =¬(p∨¬q)∨(p∨¬q)=\top$

Comment: @Manx, I see. I didn't see that they were the same thing just one had its order the other way around. Thank you!